# Winforms INotifyPropertyChanged for radio button backColor

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, viewmodel, inotifypropertychanged

Is there a way to change the `BackColor` of a `RadioButton` that is already bound to a `ViewModel` property?

Basically I am using a `ViewModel` with `INotifyPropertyChanged` and I want to change the `BackColor` of the radio buttons according to the Bool property it is bound to. So if `true` then set the backcolor to `Green` otherwise `default`.

Here is my attempt so far which obviously doesn't work. I am pretty sure my double binding is not correct?

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private bool _prop1;
        public bool Prop1 {
            get
            {
                return _prop1;
            }
            set
            {
               if (value == _prop1) return;
    
               _prop1= value;
               OnPropertyChanged(); 
               OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackColor));               
            } 
        }

        private bool _prop2;
        public bool Prop2{ 
            get
            {
                return _prop2;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == _prop2) return;
    
               _prop2= value;
               OnPropertyChanged(); 
               OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackColor));   
            } 
        }

        public Color BackColor => Color.Green;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
```

Form

```
public partial class Form1
{
    private ViewModel _viewModel;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupBindings();
    }

    public void SetupBindings()
    {
        radioButton1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.Prop1), true);
        radioButton1.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.BackColor ), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        radioButton2.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.Prop2), true);
        radioButton2.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.BackColor ), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not declare a `BackColor` property in your VM, bind it to the background color of your radio button, and change the value of 'BackColor` appropriately when your other properties change?

Comment: @Sach already declared in my VM `public Color BackColor => Color.Green;`

Comment: So, bind it to the background property of your radio button instead of binding Prop1 and 2 which is what you're doing right now. Then, when Prop1 and 2 change, change the `BackColor` property accordingly.

Comment: Same as above. BTW, you're setting the value after you have notified the change, not sure why the notification is triggered just when the value is `true` (you should check `_prop1 != value`)

Comment: @Sach sorry there was typo when copying my code to the SOF editor. So for each radioButton I am binding the `Prop1` and `Prop2` along with the `BackColor` property. Is this correct? When I test this both buttons are green ?

Comment: @Jimi good correction thank you :)

Comment: I don't see you calling `SetupBinding()` in your code posted here. Do you do that in your actual code?

Comment: @Sach I do.... just thinking of the binding of Background color of radio buttons....if I share the same property `BackColor` will it not always show the same color for both of them?

Comment: I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok think I have solved my problem :)

So created two separate properties for `BackColor` for each radio buttons in my ViewModel

```
private bool _prop1;
public bool Prop1 {
    get
    {
        return _prop1;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == _prop1) return;
    
        _prop1= value;
        OnPropertyChanged(); 
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Radio1ButtonBackColor));               
    } 
}

private bool _prop2;
public bool Prop2{ 
    get
    {
       return _prop2;
    }
    set
    {
       if (value == _prop2) return;
    
       _prop2= value;
       OnPropertyChanged(); 
       OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Radio2ButtonBackColor));   
    } 
}
public Color Radio1ButtonBackColor => Prop1? Color.Green : default;
public Color Radio2ButtonBackColor => Prop2? Color.Green : default;
```

And Bound them to the radio button `backColor` property

```
public void SetupBindings()
{
     radioButton1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.Prop1), true);
     radioButton1.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.RadioButton1BackColor Radio1ButtonBackColor), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
 
     radioButton2.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.Prop2), true);
     radioButton2.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.RadioButton2BackColor), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
```